# How to get all values from a json string with Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm using the Newtonsoft class to read a JSON text, and I'm having difficulty getting all the values, can anyone help me with how can I do it?

The address is this
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/letanure/3012978/raw/36fc21d9e2fc45c078e0e0e07cce3c81965db8f9/estados-cidades.json

My code try

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim sr As StreamReader

Dim json As String

req = WebRequest.Create("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/letanure/3012978/raw/36fc21d9e2fc45c078e0e0e07cce3c81965db8f9/estados-cidades.json")
response = req.GetResponse()

sr = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
json = sr.ReadToEnd

Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

For Each t As JToken In o.Descendants()
    MsgBox(t(1).ToString)
Next
```

Comment: try using `JavaScriptSerializer` class (_available since 3.5_) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In what manner does your current code fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to store the deserialized data

```
Public Class Estado
    Public Property sigla As String
    Public Property nome As String
    Public Property cidades As String()
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property estados As Estado()
End Class
```

then deserialize it

```
Dim result As Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Data)(json)
```

Now data can be accessed

```
Dim firstItemName As String = result(0).nome
```

Comment: And how do I go about all the cities?